# Why will my trackpad and keyboard not work with dual booted Kali Linux on Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard, multi-boot, kali-linux

Due to my current circumstances, I need to dual boot Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro (2018).  I managed to burn the image onto an external flash drive and load to the desktop in the Kali OS.

My problem is that once I get to the desktop, my mouse and keyboard do not work at all. How do I fix this problem? Do I need to install a driver? If so, how could I go about this?

(I am relatively new to Linux, so a more in depth explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Please read: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) You may want to start out with a more beginner-friendly distro before moving up to Kali.

Comment: You can try an External Keyboard / Mouse.  If your MAC supports a USB RFI device, you could use LogiTech keyboard/mouse combination.   You can also try Kali in a Virtual Machine on your MAC. The VMware keyboard / mouse drivers work in Kali - I am using this now in a VM.

Comment: @Worthwelle I just tried dual booting with Debian instead(this is the linux Distro im familiar with) and I get the same problem.  Once I get past the boot menu and options and am asked to select a language, the mouse and keyboard no longer function.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I've not used Kali, but in the interest of helping, I've seen several posts where `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` solved the issue. Are you able to execute that? If not, you may be able to use a Live CD of a distro that does work or has an on-screen keyboard to add this to the `/etc/crontab` file using the [`@reboot`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438852) function.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier Kali images were not detecting Apple keyboard and trackpad. But the latest release v2020.4 supports in both Installer and Live mode.

I am not sure whether the keyboard or trackpad was working while installation, but was once I installed for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Macs use the T2 security chip as the controller for the input devices, which was not supported by the Linux kernel until version 5.4. Kali 2020.1 and newer use newer kernels that should support the input drivers.

You might want to use the latest version that should have the drivers included.
https://www.kali.org/releases/